# How to calculate difference between two sensors and make alert in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've got few streams from few Kafka topics (if it possible to do other way and easier I could make one topic or any other modifications) with sensors measurements into JSON messages:

```
topic1: {'data': {'temp':25.2, 'sensore_name': 'T1', 'timestamp': 123123131}, 'compare_with': 'T2'}
topic2: {'data': {'temp':28, 'sensore_name': 'T2', 'timestamp': 53543543}, 'compare_with': 'T1'}
topic3: {'data': {'temp':32, 'sensore_name': 'T3', 'timestamp': 6757575}, 'compare_with': 'T2'}
topic4: {'data': {'temp':12, 'sensore_name': 'T3', 'timestamp': 67856222}, 'compare_with': 'T1'}
```

I need to compare T1.data.temp - T2.data.temp (I need to compare it with EXACTLY last measurement of other sensor (Shown in compare_with), because measurements could come with different frequency: T1 1 message per sec, T2 1 message per 5 sec., T3 3 message per sec.) calculate AVG from this difference in 1 houre window, and if this difference more than AVG, then make Alarm to somewhere... Don't understand how to do it?

Flink 1.17.1
Java 17